# Unable to set state after getting document data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to do a User Profile page and after getting the data from Firestore, I'm unable to set the data into the `userProfile` state.

```
  const {userProfile, setUserProfile} = useState(null);

  const getUserProfile = async () => {
    await firestore().collection("Users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(documentSnapshot => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        console.log('User data from Firestore: ', documentSnapshot.data());
        setUserProfile(documentSnapshot.data());
      }
    });    
  }

  useEffect (() => {
    if (userProfile == null) {
      getUserProfile();
      console.log("User Data in userProfile state: ", userProfile);
    }
  }, [userProfile])
```

I got this error:

[image]

The console log shows that the `userProfile` state is undefined, however, I can retrieve the data from Firestore without any issues as shown in the console log.

[image]

Comment: 1. `documentSnapshot.exists` is a function. You need to do `if(documentSnapshot.exists())`. 2. What happens if you `console.log(documentSnapshot.data())` twice before calling `setUserProfile`? I'm curious if maybe `documentSnapshot.data()` cannot be called twice.

Comment: Looks like you are using the web version 8 api, your code closely matches the docs, with the exception of calling `documentSnapshot.data()` twice as mentioned in the first comment. What is the result if you save `documentSnapshot.data()` locally first, then log the value and enqueue the state update? For the error, just add a catch block to the Promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const {userProfile, setUserProfile} = useState(null); <----- error is here

  const getUserProfile = async () => {
    await firestore().collection("Users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(documentSnapshot => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        console.log('User data from Firestore: ', documentSnapshot.data());
        setUserProfile(documentSnapshot.data());
      }
    });    
  }

  useEffect (() => {
    if (userProfile == null) {
      getUserProfile();
      console.log("User Data in userProfile state: ", userProfile);
    }
  }, [userProfile])
```

Instead of of `const {userProfile, setUserProfile} = useState(null);`

replace it with `const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);`

Because u are using
`curly brackets` in `{userProfile,setUserProfile}`

u need to replace it with
`square brackets` `[userProfile,setUserProfile]`